# Ajax request works fine only in index page

Tags: jquery, ajax, cordova, cordova-3

I am using one of mobile apps template which is built in framework7 to develop my app on cordova, i need to make ajax requests on every page to get its data from the php web service. i made one request in index.html page and it works fine and not working when try to copy the same request to another page

Here is the index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, minimal-ui">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black">
    <title></title>

    <!-- font Raleway link -->  
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:400,600,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Slab:400,300,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>

    <!--<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">-->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'"/>

    <!-- all css here -->
    <!-- Path to Framework7 Library CSS-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.ios.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/framework7.ios.colors.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swipebox.css">             
    <!-- font-awesome.min CSS -->      
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <!-- style CSS -->          
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <!-- style CSS -->          
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.css">



  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- login screen  start-->
      <div class="pagelogin">
        <div class="page-content login-screen-content registerbody">
            <div class="register-content">
                <h3><img src="img/logo2.png" alt=""></h3>
                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;background-color:#FF0004;border-radius:10px;padding:5px;margin-bottom:15px;display:none" id="reslt"></div>
                <form action="SignIn()" method="post">
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <span>Username:</span><br>
                        <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <span>Password:</span><br>
                        <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" placeholder="***********">
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <a data-popup=".popup-forgetpass" class="open-popup"   href="#">Forget Password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input style="background: #5c8bf7 none repeat scroll 0 0;border: medium none;color: #ffffff;height:60px;" type="button" class="button button-big" onClick="SignIn()" value="Login">
                    </div>                      
                </form> 




                <p></p>
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
  <!-- login screen  start-->
    <!-- forget password  start-->


<script type="text/javascript">

function SignIn() {
var UserName = $("input[name=\"UserName\"]").val();
var Password = $("input[name=\"Password\"]").val();
    $.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        url        : 'http://example.com/index.php/mobile/users/login/' + UserName + '/' + Password,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType   : 'json',
        cache: false,

        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'true')
            {
                document.location = "home.html";
            }else{
                document.getElementById('reslt').style.display = "block";
                $("#reslt").html('Username or password incorrect..!');
            }
        },

        error: function(req, err){ console.log('my message : ' + err); }
    });
};


</script>






 <div class="popup popup-forgetpass">
    <div class="registerbody">
        <a href="#" class="close-popup closebutton"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
        <div class="register-content">
            <h3><img src="img/logo2.png" alt=""></h3>
            <form action="#">
                <div class="inputbox">
                    <span>Email:</span><br>
                    <input type="email" name="password" placeholder="email@gmail.com">
                </div>
                <div class="inputbox">
                    <button class="button button-big">Remember me</button>
                </div>                      
            </form> 
            <p></p>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
  <!-- forget password  end-->
  <!-- resister popup start-->
<div class="popup popup-register">
    <div class="registerbody">
            <a href="#" class="close-popup closebutton"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></a>
         <div class="register-content">
            <h3><img src="img/logo2.png" alt=""></h3>
                <form action="#">
                <div class="inputbox">
                    <span>Full Name:</span><br>
                    <input type="text" name="fulname" placeholder="Full Name">
                </div>
                <div class="inputbox">
                    <span>Username:</span><br>
                    <input type="text" name="username2" placeholder="Username">
                </div>
                <div class="inputbox">
                    <span>Email:</span><br>
                    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email@gmail.com">
                </div>
                <div class="inputbox">
                    <span>Password:</span><br>
                    <input type="password" name="password2" placeholder="***********">
                </div>
                <div class="inputbox">
                    <button class="button button-big">Sign Up</button>
                </div>                  
            </form>
        </div>
     </div>
</div>
  <!-- resister popup start-->  
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/Push.js"></script>
    <!-- Js -->
    <!-- jquery-1.11.3.min js -->         
    <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Path to Framework7 Library JS --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/framework7.min.js"></script>
    <!--jquery.swipebox js --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.swipebox.js"></script>
    <!-- Path to your app js --> 
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/my-app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Here is the another page which is the request didn't work

```
<!-- We don't need full layout here, because this page will be parsed with Ajax-->
<!-- Top Navbar-->
<div class="navbar">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="left"><a href="#" class="back link"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i><span>Back</span></a></div>
    <div class="center sliding"><h4>Sign In</h4></div>
    <div class="right">
      <!-- Right link contains only icon - additional "icon-only" class--><a href="#" data-panel="right"  class="link icon-only open-panel"> <i class="fa fa-navicon"></i></a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="pages">
  <!-- Page, data-page contains page name-->
  <div data-page="about" class="page">
    <!-- Scrollable page content-->
    <div class="page-content">
      <div class="content-block">
        <div class="content-block-inner">


            <div class="register-content">
                <h3><img src="img/logo2.png" alt=""></h3>
                <div style="color:#FFFFFF;width:80%;margin-left:auto;margin-right:auto;text-align:center;background-color:#FF0004;border-radius:10px;padding:5px;margin-bottom:15px;display:none" id="reslt"></div>
                <form action="SignIn()" method="post">
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <span>Username:</span><br>
                        <input type="text" name="UserName" id="UserName" placeholder="Username">
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <span>Password:</span><br>
                        <input type="password" name="Password" id="Password" placeholder="***********">
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <a data-popup=".popup-forgetpass" class="open-popup"   href="#">Forget Password?</a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="inputbox">
                        <input style="background: #5c8bf7 none repeat scroll 0 0;border: medium none;color: #ffffff;height:60px;" type="button" class="button button-big" onClick="SignIn()" value="Login">
                    </div>                      
                </form> 
            </div>




       </div>



<script type="text/javascript">
function SignIn() {
var UserName = $("input[name=\"UserName\"]").val();
var Password = $("input[name=\"Password\"]").val();
    $.ajax({
        type       : "POST",
        url        : 'http://example.com/index.php/mobile/users/login/' + UserName + '/' + Password,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType   : 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function(data) {
            if(data == 'true')
            {
                document.location = "home.html";
            }else{
                document.getElementById('reslt').style.display = "block";
                $("#reslt").html('Username or password incorrect..!');
            }
        },
        error: function(req, err){ console.log('my message : ' + err); }
    });
};
</script>


        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Any idea to try ??

Answer (score 0):

1. Add your script **after** the jQuery inclusion.
2. Edit your form using `onSubmit="SignIn()"` instead of `action="SignIn()"`
3. `request didn't work`, which errors appears?
4. In the second page are you loading jQuery?

Comment: in the second page i tried to load jQuery but with no hope

Comment: Put a console.log() inside the `SignIn()` and check if it's invoked. I think the function is never fired.

Comment: how i can do it as i am new in cordova and i am using Dreamweaver for editing and node.js command window

Comment: You just have to write `console.log('test');` inside your SignIn function. Maybe is better a reading of JavaScript instead of a mobile app...

Comment: I need you to know that when i put the request in iframe it works fine .. so what !!!